# jQuery: позволяет ли метод find() уменьшить количество обращений в DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Правильно ли я понял, что в приведённом ниже коде мы выполняем ресурсозатратную операцию обращения к DOM только один раз, а дальше уже работаем с `jQuery`-объектами с хорошей производительностью?

```
<ul class="someClass">
    <li class="subclass1"></li>
    <li class="subclass2"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="someClass">
    <li class="subclass1"></li>
    <li class="subclass2"></li>
</ul>

var elementsSet = $('.someClass');
var elementsSubset1 = elementsSet.find('.subclass1')
var elementsSubset2 = elementsSet.find('.subclass2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С появлением в браузерах нативного метода querySelectorAll - это уже на самом деле не столь важно. jQuery уже не надо самостоятельно обходить дерево - он делегирует это сильно оптимизированным алгоритмам браузера.

Единственное, при использовании селектора с id - лучше использовать find:

```
// будет использоваться querySelectorAll по всему документу
$('#myid .myclass') 

// будет использоваться очень быстрый метод 
// getElementById, а затем querySelectorAll по меньшему дереву
$('#myid').find('.myclass')
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Отлично, что современные разработчики совремнных браузеров работают над проблемой медлительности обращения к DOM. Поскорей бы старые браузеры канули в лету :)